# When an external function is called, cppcheck cannot check for an uninitialized variable error

Tags: c, variables, initialization, cppcheck

```
#include "test.h"

static int test(){
 test_t i;
 init(i);
}

static test_t init(test_t const a){
 test_c(&a);
 return a;
}
```

When I use Cppcheck to check this file ,it reports uninitialized variable at  `init(i);`.
But it does not report uninitialized variable when I delete the declaration of `init` .

```
#include "test.h"

static int test(){
    test_t i;
    init(i);
}
```

Is there any solution for cppcheck reports uninitialized variable when calling external functions?

Comment: How does the second version even compile? If the tool doesn't know what `init` is then how can it tell that `init(i)` is making use of the variable? It could as well be a macro `#define init(x) x=0` or whatever.

Comment: this is a example ,function init is defined  in other file

Comment: But where is it _declared_? A function declaration needs to be visible inside the same translation unit and placed before the `test` definition.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The same translation unit is the key of this problem

Comment: Since CppCheck might interpret this as C++, it could think of `init(test_t &p)` and then `i` might not be used unitialized.